# How do i call by reference in python

Tags: python

I've wrote his c code :

```
 void cautare_element_liber(int *linie,int *coloana)
{
                                                        //Cauta un element liber in matrice transmitand linia si coloana acestuia
    *linie=0;
    *coloana=0;
    int i,j,ok=0;
    for(i=1;i<=9 && ok==0;i++)
        for(j=1;j<=9&& ok==0;j++)
        if(a[i][j] == 0 )
        {
        *linie = i;
        *coloana=j;
        ok=1;
        }
}
    cautare_element_liber(&linie,&coloana);
```

And in python it give me an error at the cautare_element_liber(linie,coloana)

```
def cautareElementLiber(linie, coloana):
    linie = 0
    coloana = 0
    ok = 0
    for iIterator in range(1, 10) and ok == 0:
        for jIterator in range(1, 10) and ok == 0:
            if a[iIterator][jIterator] == 0:
                linie = i
                coloana = jIterator
                ok = 1

cautareElementLiber(linie, coloana)
```

"linie" is not defined

Comment: Did you define `linie` anywhere before using it as an argument to cautareElementLiber?  Are you perhaps wanting `linie` and `coloana` to be optional arguments?  In that case, try `def cautareElementLiber(linie=0, coloana=0):` and eliminate the first two lines of the function.

Comment: The correct way in Python is to return a tuple of output parameters: `def cautareElementLiber(): ... return (linie, coloana)` and then use `linie, coloana = cautareElementLiver()`